# how can I make a mysql search allow two separate search categories?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put together a search bar that will allow you to search a list of businesses by typing in a city or state but it will only search by city no matter what I try to add. is this possible or should I need to start over and write new with mysqli?

here is the code:

```
.

$result1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE city LIKE '%$search_term%' ORDER BY state") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());

$count= mysql_num_rows($result1);

if ($count == 0){ 
echo "<fieldset><b>No Results Found for Search Query '$search_term'</b> 
</fieldset>";

}else{

print "<table border=1>\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){  
$images_field= 
$row['images'];
$image_show= "/$images_field";
$city= $row['city']; 
$state= 
$row['state'];  
print "<tr>\n"; 
print "\t<td>\n"; 
echo "<div class='gallery' align=center><a target='_blank' href=". $image_show."><img src=". $image_show." width='300' height='200'></a></div>";
print "</td>\n";
print "\t<td>\n"; 
print "<font face=arial size=4/><div align=center>$city</div></font>"; 
print "</td>\n";
print "\t<td>\n"; 
echo "<font face=arial size=4/>$state</font>";
print "</td>\n";
print "</tr>\n"; 
} 

print "</table>\n"; 
}

.
```

I tried adding 'or state' , 'AND state' after 'WHERE city' but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query should works

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE city LIKE '%$search_term%' OR state LIKE '%$search_term%' ORDER BY state
```

Comment: that worked, smh, funny thing is I tried that but used AND instead of OR lol thank you very much!